# junit test case for spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

we are developing an application using spring mvc framework. I have given all the classes below, please suggest how to write a junit test case for the below scenario.

I want to write a junit test case for the  validateAccountInformation(requestDTO) method which is called in validateAccount(..) method of LPAValidator.java class. Below is my junit test case followed by the java classes. Actual call goes from the LPAController.java as shown in the below code.

LPAControllerTest.java

```
       @Test(groups = "manual")
        public void submitRequestForLPAAccountTest()
        {
       // businessCalendar.nextBusinessDay(
      //                LocalDateHelper.today(), LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS)
     //i want to write the test case for the above commented logic, 
     //if business days is not equal to twenty days, test should fail. 
        }
```

LPAController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lpa/{accNumber}/spread, method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody LPAResponseDTO accountSearch(@RequestBody final LPARequestDTO clientrequestBody,
                                        @PathVariable final String accNumber, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //some logic goes here

final LPAAccountResponse domainResponse = service.submitRequestForLPAAccount(requestBody);

    }
```

LPAServiceImpl.java

```
@PermitAll
@NonTransactional
public LPAResponse submitRequestForLPAAccount(final LPARequest requestDTO)
{
    return lpaRepository.submitRequestForLPAAccount(requestDTO));
}
```

LPARepository.java

```
    @PermitAll
    @NonTransactional
    public LPAResponse submitRequestForLPAAccount(final LPARequest requestDTO)
    {
    //some logic
    lpaValidator.validateAccount(requestDTO);

    //some logic

    }
```

LPAValidator.java -- java class for validations

```
@component
class LPAValidator{
    @Inject
    private BusinessCalendar businessCalendar;

            void validateAccount(final LPARequest requestDTO) throws Exception {
            try {
                validateAccountInformation(requestDTO);
                } catch(Exception e){
                }
        }

            private void validateAccountInformation(final LPARequest requestDTO) throws Exception{
                final accDate lpaAccDate = requestDTO.getLPADate();
                final LocalDate twentyBussinessDays = businessCalendar.nextBusinessDay(
                    LocalDateHelper.today(), LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS); //i want to write 
    //test case for this line of code, if business days given is more than twenty test should fail.
                //some logic here
        }
```

Please suggest what needs to be added in LPAControllerTest.java to test the nextBusinessDay(..) as discussed above.

Comment: Although discussions are there, I think it's more common to write LPAController as LpaController, only capitalizing new words, and not abbreviations (even though they are). Of course you'll have HTTPServlet (or HttpServlet) which kinda breaks it, but...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to write an integration test in which your controller is called, which then calls all the subclasses until the validator is triggered. That is not a traditional 'unit test'.

A traditional unit test would just test the validator straight up, and nothing more.

Nevertheless, when writing an integration test, [spring documentation to the rescue](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)
In short, it'll require you to create an applicationcontext with all the necessary scaffolding, and then use a mockMvc call to do a GET on the created application.

If you want to test the validator, use simple mocking framework:
See [http://mockito.org]
Gives you something like this:

```
@Mock BusinessCalendar businessCalendarMock;
@Mock LPARequest mockRequest;
@Mock accDate mockDate;
@Mock LocalDate mockLocalDate;
@InjectMocks LPAValidator lpaValidator = new LPAValidator();
@Test public void testValidateAccount() {
    when(mockRequest.getLPAdate()).thenReturn(mockDate);
    when(businessCalendar.nextBusinessDay(LocalDateHelper.today(),LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS).thenReturn(mockLocalDate);
    // continue your test from here
   lpaValidator.validateAccount( mockRequest);
   verify(businessCalendar).nextBusinessDay(LocalDateHelper.today(),LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS);
    // although if the use of mockLocalDate is integral to your code, it'll probably show before and no verify is necessary;
```

Comment: As i'm new to spring, the link u provided is confusing me. My application flow is same as shown in above mentioned java classes. can u please provide a code snippet to call validateAccountInformation(requestDTO) method in test case method submitRequestForLPAAccountTest() of junit test class - Koos Gadellaa. Thanks

Comment: I want to write a test case to test if businessCalendar.nextBusinessDay(  LocalDateHelper.today(), LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS) which is in validateAccountInformation(..) method is given 20 days omly as input (i.e., LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS should be assigned to 20) . If any value is given other than 20, test should fail.

Comment: If you want to test BusinessCalendar.nextBusinessDay() you write a junit testcase for BusinessCalendar.  
In it, you test whether an exception is thrown for the appropriate methods.  
In your validator, you probably inject your businesscalendar object (if not, you should. Either with spring-DI, or if that's impossible, just overwrite the field with spring-tests `ReflectionUtils` with a mock, so you can verify that the appropriate call is made.

Comment: Koos Gadellaa - Can u give an example if possible, thanks.

Comment: How should i write junit test case to test this line of code : final LocalDate twentyBussinessDays = businessCalendar.nextBusinessDay(LocalDateHelper.today(), LPAConstants.TWENTY_BUSSINESS_DAYS); . Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: LPAValidator class is not accessible in test class as its  not a public class and placed in some other package.
Following errors are shown : LPAValidator is not public cannot be accessed from outside package.
Cannot find symbol class lpaDate. Please suggest what modifications i can do to write junit test class for the above scenario. thanks.

Comment: Put your testcase in the same package as the LPAValidator. And request.getLPADate returns an accDate (horrible name, but it's your code). So the mockDate should have an accDate as type.